# Rails 3 - PaperClip - Storage options for lot of directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, storage

I want to use the paperclip plugin and I saw in the documentation the way to change the path for storage.

As I will have thousands of items for my model (and directories at the same level), I want to know how I can format my :id (and explode it) to do something, if id is 32768 for example, like:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/3/2/7/6/8/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

What is the best way to explode the :id and send the new path to paperclip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Paperclip::Interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations). You can create a custom interpolation that uses the exploded id. First you need to use the custom interpolation in your path:

```
 :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:exploded_id/:style/:filename"
```

Then add a definition to the model like this:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :exploded_id do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.exploded_id
end
```

And a method for exploding the id:

```
def exploded_id
  self.id.to_s.scan(/./).join('/')
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks. Just need to remove "self" : def exploded_id end

Comment: Silly me. Fixed it. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip provides a build-in way to deal with folder structures:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

This will give directory structure

```
.../:attachment/000/032/768/:style/...
```

This doesn't use your requested folder format, but probably is more efficient.

**Bonus**

If you are converting from existing folder structure to this id partitioned one, check and see this [Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/3313170) which moves the folders around for you. Just in case, please do some testing with dummy folder on the server before running it.